# Making Flappy Bird game in Unity and the Spawn script for the pipes won't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my Spawner.cs script to work in Unity on a flappy bird game I am making. I am following this [tutorial](https://weeklyhow.com/flappy-bird-unity-tutorial/).

For some reason only one set of pipes will cross the screen and none others appear. I am a beginner and appreciate any help in this matter. Here is the code for the Spawner.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float queueTime = 1.5f;
    private float time = 0;
    public GameObject ObstaclePipes;

    public float height;
    
    void Start () {
        GameObject newpipe = Instantiate(ObstaclePipes);
        newpipe.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-height, height), 0);
    }
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(time > queueTime)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(ObstaclePipes);
            go.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-height, height), 0);

            time = 0;

            Destroy(go, 10);
        }

        time += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the obstacles.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class obstacles : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float speed;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += ((Vector3.left * speed) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: "None others appear" what does this mean? Are these obstacles spawned into the scene and not visible in the screen or are they not spawned at all?

Comment: I believe they are spawning but not visible. The Hierarchy window displays a clone of the obstacle as I'm playing the game but not pipes are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the obstacles are spawning and not visible on the screen, the obstacle sprite renderers are rendered behind the background. This behavior is common when working with 2D games. To solve this, we have to use [sorting layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SortingLayer.html).

Sorting layer allows us to set the render order of sprites. In your case, we have to set the order of sorting layer for your obstacles so that they spawn in front of the background instead of behind it.

Hence in the sprite renderer component of the obstacle, set its **Order In Layer** to a value more than `0` as `0` is the default value which was the same for both background and obstacle. In our case, let's set it to `1`. Now, the obstacles are rendered first, and then the background which lets us see the obstacles on the screen.

[image]