# How do I instantiate a prefab in the middle of the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My game requires a prefab to be instantiated in the middle of the screen. Currently I have the code set up like this:

```
 Instantiate(_Confirm,new Vector3(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2,0),Quaternion.identity);
```

However, when I run the code, I find that it object has been instantiated far away from my viewport.

EDIT: It's a 2D game

Comment: Middle of the screen? Ok, is it a 2D game? Or is it a 3D game? If it is a 3D game, how far from the camera should the prefab be instantiated?

Comment: Yes it's a 2D game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
Vector2 spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
Instantiate(_Confirm, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Oh right, btw, I have a small problem, I want the prefab to appear on top of everything else. I tried making spawnPos a Vector3 and and giving it a high third value, but that didn't seem to have solved it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73059162/17235431. Your gameobject has a component "SpriteRenderer". Change the value of "Order In Layer" to a value something like 10